Starting a task from a running gitlab CI/CD task
The question is, is it possible to run one task from another? For example, here is gitlab-ci.yml:
task1:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "start task1" 
    - touch trigger-file.txt
    - sleep 120 
    - echo "finish task1" 

task2:
  script:
    - echo "start task2" 
    - # code ...
    - echo "finish task2" 


Is there a way to make it so that after creating the file trigger-file.txt task2 was started without waiting for task1 to complete. In this case, the logs would look like this:
start task1
# create trigger-file.txt
start task2
finish task2
finish task1

The order of the finish task* is not important in this case
This is necessary when, for example, large files are being assembled in task1, and I need the first of the files to be assembled, and in order not to waste time waiting for all the files to be assembled, I want to create a parallel task when it processes the only file I need. There is no way to divide task1 into subtasks

I came up with this solution: use needs: [] and in scripts specify the expectation of the file I need, but this does not look like a good solution to the issue

Unfortunately, GitLab CI/CD doesn’t support native interaction between jobs while they're running. GitLab starts a job, captures its output, and doesn’t provide a way to interact with it until it completes.
However, if you're using a shell runner and can ensure that all your jobs run on the same machine, you can use a workaround. For example (as you already implied), one job could create a file in a shared directory, and another job could monitor for this file’s presence before proceeding. For distributed or Docker runners, you might achieve a similar result by using a shared database flag or uploading a file to a cloud storage service like S3.
Natively, however, you could probably only insert a fixed delay in minutes using the delay keyword in case you can estimate the wait time.
